# How to find R's domain when using the inverse transformation method to create random-variate generation?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

The question:

Develop a random-variate generator for a random variable $X$ with the pdf

\begin{equation}
  f(x)=\begin{cases}
    e^{2x}, & \text{if $ -\infty < x \leq0$}.\\
    e^{-2x}, & \text{if $ 0 < x < \infty$}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Now I have calculated the CDF:

\begin{equation}
  F(x)=\begin{cases}
    \frac{e^{2x}}{2}, & \text{if $ -\infty < x \leq0$}.\\
    \frac{1 - e^{-2x}}{2}, & \text{if $ 0 < x < \infty$}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

getting $F(x) = R$ and isolating X isn't really a problem. I simply don't understand how to find R's domain. "if : $ 0 < R \leq a$" How do I find $a$?

Answer (score 1):

The cumulative distribution function (CDF) of a random variable X is a function F(x) that gives the probability that the random variable X is less than or equal to x. In other words, F(x) = P(X ≤ x).

In this case, the CDF of the random variable X is given by

F(x) = { e^(2x^2), if -∞ < x ≤ 0
{ 1 - e^(-2x^2), if 0 < x < ∞

The function F(x) is defined only for x in the range [-∞, ∞], so the domain of R is also [-∞, ∞]. The range of R is the set of all possible values that F(x) can take, which in this case is the interval [0, 1]. This means that the range of R is the interval [0, 1] and the domain of R is [-∞, ∞].

To generate random variates for the random variable X, you can generate random numbers in the range [0, 1] and use the inverse of the CDF to map them to the range of X. For example, if you generate the random number R = 0.5, then the corresponding value of X is given by the inverse of the CDF: X = F^(-1)(0.5). You can use the equation for F(x) to solve for F^(-1)(x) and find the value of X corresponding to R = 0.5. This process can be repeated for other values of R to generate a sequence of random variates for the random variable X.

Comment: So just to confirm, I don't have an actual "range" of R as it is assumed that it will be between 0 and 1? What would my end result be then? Is it an "Xi =" with both inverted CDFs in curly brackets? Or do I have only a single equation?